# PayPalExpress Processor Declines my order says Security header not valid

Tags: rest, paypal, payment-gateway, sap-commerce-cloud

I have got a Paypal order, with a order id (`O-123213XXXX`) from Paypal. I am trying to `Authorize` it via Hybris Storefront. Hybris will pass the payload to third party when user clicks on place order button, that third party will authorize the payment by communicating to `PayPalExpress` processor.

My payment is reaching till the processor and I am getting the response like `[cart] 10002 Security Header not valid`. I searched online and came to know that its something related to invalid API Credentials. They are suggesting not to get confused with live Paypal credentials with sandbox credentials.

I have cross-checked everything,

1) I have a Paypal button at my Hybris Storefront which user click when they wish to pay using Paypal. This will create the order.
2) After which, I am logging in using my sandbox test user account of type personal to approve the order via Paypal popup window.
3) Next, I execute that order. Before that, I need the bearer `access-token` using my online store's "Sandbox" Client ID and Secret Key combination in another REST call. (Just to mention... this online store/app is associate with a sandbox account of type "Business")
Once I get the token, I execute the order via another REST call using that access-token.
4) Now I get the Order Id from Paypal so that once the order is placed in Hybris, it will be Authorized and then Captured at a later stage. (Thats the plan...)

I have noticed in the Paypal developer account that the Business account associated with my online store/app has some credentials such as Username, Password and Signature.. But I am not using them anywhere in my flow.
(Those are for SOAP/NVP Calls that what they say in docs..)

and now I am getting 10002 Security header invalid response from processor.

As per my understanding I am not using any live credentials anywhere but the sandbox.

or am I missing something related to those mentioned credentials I am not using anywhere??

Comment: Issue Resolved - the credentials were wrongly configured by my payments team. Instead of the one mentioned above.. they used Rest Api client id for signature and  secret key for password and were using sandbox email id in place of username.